# How to call JavaScript (in browser) from Kotlin Native Wasm, passing parameters?

Tags: kotlin, browser, webassembly, kotlin-js-interop

*Please excuse me that I don't know if I should ask about all basic types in one post or separately.*

Main questions:

1. How do I pass an array of floats from Kotlin to JS?
2. How about other "simple" types?  Like a float, string?
3. What about other types like `set`, `map` and even data classes?

---

I have this at the end of my Kotlin Main File

```
@SymbolName("callback")
external fun cb(<......>)
```

If the types in the `cb()` definition matches what I am passing from the `main()`, e.g. `Int`, `Float`, then `cb()` from the browser will get correct values.

If I am using `Any`, then all I'll get is an integer (which I guess should be a pointer to the memory).

I have tried to inspect `heap` but to no avail in how to retrieve the int, float, strings that I passed to `cb()` via Kotlin.

For Arrays, I noticed that there are `JsArray` in [jsinterop](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlinx.wasm.jsinterop/index.html) package, but I cannot find good references on how to use it.

One thing I have noticed is that I can get an array of integers via Arenas:

```
    val arena = allocateArena()
    pushIntToArena(arena, 1)
    pushIntToArena(arena, 12)
```

Then I'll get the array via `konan_dependencies.env.arenas`.

But, how do I get an array of floats? Please advise.

P.S. I am using `konan` plugin in my `build.gradle` for compiling to Wasm32.  I pass `callback` to Wasm by adding the function to `window.konan.libraries` in `module.wasm.js`:

```
    var konan = {
      libraries: [
        { "callback": function(msg) { console.trace(msg); } }
      ],
    }
```